# Is every $\sigma$-algebra generated by some measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory

I think this statement should be intuitively true, but I can't prove it myself or find the proof elsewhere. Could you help me, please?

Consider a general measurable space $(X,\mathcal{B})$ and any other measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$. Does there exist (for every $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$) a function (measurable) $f:\Omega\rightarrow(X,\mathcal{B})$ such that $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(f)$? In other words, is every $\sigma$-algebra generated by some measurable function?

Comment: Can you clarify the quantifiers? You are asking whether there is such a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{B})$, which will generate every $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ via some measurable $f$? (Also, what is a "general measurable space"?)

Comment: Given measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal{B})$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, does there exists a function $f:\Omega\rightarrow(X,\mathcal{B})$ such that $f$ generates $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Of course not. For $X=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathcal B$ the power set, every $\sigma$-algebra of $\sigma(f)$ has at most four elements.

Comment: And if I consider $|\mathcal{A}|\leq|\mathcal{B}|$?

Comment: This is the wrong forum for the question..... Answer: YES, in the case: real-valued measurable function $f$ and countably-generated $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$.  But otherwise, perhaps not.  So, if $\mathcal B$ is countably generated, then so is $\sigma(f)$.

Comment: I am asking because I read, that $\mathcal{C}:=\{ C\subset \mathbb{R}: C\text{ Is countable or } C^c \text{ is countable}\}$ Is not generated by any function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ And I didn't believe it. Thanks for clarification

Comment: That $\sigma$-algebra is not countably generated (a fun exercise), and so by Gerald's observation this is not generated by any measurable function via the Borel sets, which are countably generated.